# Re-arrange equation of sum of numerators vs sum of denominators

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

I'm working on a program and we currently use a formula as follows to compute a total ratio:

$\frac{a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n}{b_1 + b_2 + ... + b_n}$

Where $a_i$ and $b_i$ comes from same source.

Without going into detail, I will not be able to use multiple metrics from a single source so I was wondering if it was possible to rearrange this equation so that I can pre-compute some $c_i$ to obtain the same result?

I thought maybe I could do 
$(\frac{a_1}{b_1} + \frac{a_2}{b_2} + ... + \frac{a_n}{b_n})/n$

That actually appeared to work when $b$ was always the same but they appear to differ slightly when they are different.

As side questions if it is not possible to arrange the equation in a way that would satisfy the requirements:

1) Can it be proven that if $b$ is always the same, that the above formula would work?

2) Is there in fact a relationship and that these two equations will always produce similar results? We can work with a small margin of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the $b_i$ are the same your expression works.  You are applying the distributive principle to replace $\sum_i b$ with $nb$.  It also works if the ratio $\frac {a_i}{b_i}$ is constant, where the result is just $\frac {a_i}{b_i}$ for any $i$.  The more that ratio varies, the more your transformation is wrong.  Take $a_1=b_2=20, a_2=b_1=1$ for an example.  Your first is $\frac {20+1}{1+20}=1$  Your second is $(\frac {20}1+\frac 1{20})/2 \approx 10$

Comment: Cool, thanks for that!